# DBTNG sentence that sums a column from all rows of a specific user and dpm the total

Tags: database

This is my table `test_sum_expression` with columns:

`uid` (int) Stores the UID of the user.
`points` (int) Stores a number.

[image]

I have this SQL sentence which `SUMS` all `points` from user with `uid` 1.

```
SELECT uid, SUM(points) AS total_points 
FROM `test_sum_expression` 
WHERE uid = 1
GROUP BY UID;
```

Which produces
[image]

How can I produce this same sentence in DBTNG (Database: The Next Generation) format? I mean something like this:
`$query = $connection->select('test_sum_expression', 'n')...`

I have tried this

```
$query = $connection->select('test_sum_expression', 'n')
  ->fields('n', ['uid', 'points'])
  ->condition('n.uid', 1, '=')
  ->groupBy('n.uid');
$query->addExpression('SUM(n.points)', 'total_points');
$queryPoints = $query->execute();

dpm($queryPoints);
```

But without success, it produces `$queryPoints Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapper#456238 (3)`. I need to be able to get the total_points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->execute()` returns an object that implements `StatementInterface`. To get the table columns matching that query you need to either loop over that object or call one of the methods defined from that interface.

Since you are only interested to the sum of the points, I would use the following code.

```php
$query = $connection->select('test_sum_expression')
  ->condition('uid', 1);

$query->addExpression('SUM(points)', 'total_points');

$total_points = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to declare the alias in the select sentence as it is in the addExpression, it returns an error. I have a question, if I use an alias is it required to use it in the condition and addExpression too?

Comment: I am not sure you are referring to the alias associated to the expression. In that case, the alias can be only used in `addExpression()` as in `$select = $this->database->select('node__body', 't'); $select->addExpression('MAX(entity_id)');
$last = $select->execute()->fetchField();`. You can use the alias in `condition()` if the condition needs to check the value of that expression.